A complex coefficient cubic in $z$ with exactly two complex roots. Problem from Hardy's Pure Mathematics.
Given the complex-valued polynomial
$$ z^3 + 3Hz + G = 0 $$
with complex coefficients $H  $ and $ G $ and exactly two complex roots, we can apply Vieta's formula of a cubic for the sum of roots to observe that the roots are of the form
$$ k_1 = a + ib, $$
$$ k_2 = c - ib, $$
and
$$ k_3 = -a - c .$$

Does the information above necessitate that $ k_2 $ is the conjugate of $ k_1 $?

The actual question (which follows trivially if they are indeed conjugated) is to prove that
$$ l_1 = \text{Re}(k_1) $$
and
$$l_2 = \text{Re}(k_2)$$
are real roots of the equation


$$ 8x^3 + 6xH - G = 0. $$
Additionally, the signs of $ l_1 $ and $ l_2 $ are the same as the sign of
$ G $.
If the complex roots are conjugates, then this follows trivially from Vieta's formulas for the roots of a cubic in terms of the coefficients. I am struggling to prove, however, that the complex roots are indeed conjugates of one another.
Source : Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics, Chapter 3 - Examples XXI, Problem 17 from the centenary edition.

What do you mean by “sign of $G$”?  Is $G$ real or complex?

$ G $ is a complex coefficient. However, when the complex roots are conjugates it can be shown that $ G $ has to be real. As you have shown in your answer, however, that G can remain complex when the complex roots aren't conjugated, I suspect the question has been poorly framed in the source.

Hardy considers the equation $8x^3 + 6Hx - G = 0$.

And can you explain why for complex conjugates roots is follows trivially from Vieta's formulas for the roots of a cubic in terms of the coefficients.?

If the complex pair of roots are conjugates, you can directly show that all coefficients are real, and that the third root is $ 2Re(z) $, where $ z $ is one of the roots.

You should edit your question to correct the equation in $x$ which is not a quadratic equation.

Thanks for the heads up

Shouldn't the third root be $-2Re(z)$?

The question does not make sense as it is posed. Let us see what is going on.
Hardy considers two equations:
$$z^3 + 3Hz + G = 0 \tag{1} $$
and
$$8w^3 + 6Hw - G = 0 \tag{2} .$$
The assumption on $(1)$ is that there exist two complex (non-real) solutions $k_1,k_2$ and one real solution $k_3$. As you write in your question,  Vieta's formula shows that we can write
$$k_1 = a + ib, k_2 = c - ib, k_3 = -(a + c)$$
with $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$ and $b \ne 0$.
Lemma. $k_1, k_2$ are conjugate (i.e. $a = c$) iff $H, G$ are real.
Proof. We have
$$z^3 + 3Hz + G = (z-k_1)(z-k_2)(z-k_3) \tag{3}.$$
This shows that $H, G$ are real if $k_1, k_2$ are conjugate. Conversely, if $G,H$ are real, then $(z-k_1)(z-k_2)$ is a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients. It has either two real solutions or two complex conjugate solutions. The first case cannot occur by assumption on the solutions of $(1)$. $\phantom{x} \square$
Let us observe that $(3)$ yields
$$3H = (a+ib)(c-ib) - (a+ib)(a+c) - (c-ib)(a+c) \\= (a+ib)(c-ib) -(a+c)^2,\\ G = (a+ib)(c-ib)(a+c) \tag{4}.$$
Theorem. $a = \operatorname{Re}(k_1)$ is a solution of $(2)$ iff $k_1, k_2$ are conjugate. The same holds for $c = \operatorname{Re}(k_2)$.
Proof. If $a = c$, then $-2a = -(a+c)$ is a solution of $(1)$. Inserting $z = -2a$ in $(1)$ shows that $w = a$ is a solution of $(2)$.
Conversely, let $w = a$ be a solution of $(2)$. Inserting $(4)$ gives
$$8a^3 + 2(a+ib)(c-ib)a - 2(a+c)^2a - (a+ib)(c-ib)(a+c) = 0 .$$
In particular the imaginary part must be $0$, and this means
$$2(bc -ab)a - (bc - ab)(a+c)  = 0.$$
A little computation shows that the LHS of this equation is $-b(a-c)^2$.
Hence $-b(a-c)^2 = 0$ so that $a = c$ since $b \ne 0$.
The argument for $c$ is similar. $\phantom{x} \square$
Our above results show that $a$ is a solution of $(2)$ precisely for real $H, G$. And in this case it makes sense to consider the sign of $G$.
For real $H,G$ we have $a = c$, thus $G = (a^2 +b^2)2a$. Since $b \ne 0$ we see that $a^2 + b^2 > 0$ which implies that $G$ and $a$ have the same sign.

Try $a =1$, $b=1$, and $c=2$.
EDIT: easier, $x^3 -ix +1-i = (x-1-i)(x+i)(x+1)$.

In this case, the real part of the complex root doesn't satisfy the generated polynomial. So I'm guessing the question was intended for complex conjugate roots.
